# Derbi Cafe 125 stalling when changing to 1st

Tags: motorcycle, stall, switches

I have a Derbi Cafe 125. This morning I started the bike up, let it run for a few minutes, changed from N to 1st, and the bike cut out. This happens repeatedly until I walked to work. I then realized I still had the stand down when I was changing down to first. My question is, does a Derbi Cafe 125 have a stand switch or could it be something else?

The bike stalls cleanly, no jerk or anything like that. I have searched the internet for answers regarding if my bike has this switch, but can't find anything.

Comment: you could look carefully and see if you find any circuitry/switches etc. Also, in the case of a kill switch, I would assume that the engine wouldn't crank at all. In the bikes I've seen, it's also aided with a warning light to aid in safety and avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the response Paul, once i get home after work i will try it again without the stand down. If that still fails, would you say due to the bike not chugging or jerking that this problem doesn't sound mechanical?

Comment: @chilljeet sorry dude my comment above was meant for you, automatically assumed Paul answered it

Comment: What year is your Derbi?

Comment: Not to sure, could be 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was because of my stand being down :/ I've not been riding for too long and didn't even know they had that kill feature, am glad it is there, un-glad i had to walk! :)

Comment: Don't forget to select your answer as *the answer*. Glad it was something simple. Sometimes walking is good for us, though ;-)

Comment: It can be bypassed (as mine is) however that can lead to potentially catastrophic or comical events where the bike decides to trundle off on its own before falling over (speaking from experience).